# How to build a locally connected neural network with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

> I am new to tensorflow and have a hard time to build my neural network with tensorflow. My neural network has 3 layers: one input layer, one hidden layer, and one output layer. However, the input layer is not fully connected to the hidden layer. Assume that the connectivity is given by the matrix A, A[i,j] = 1 if node i (in input layer) is connected to node j (in hidden layer), and A[i,j] = 0 otherwise. Does anyone know how to do it with tensorflow?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you could implement a random dropout instead of fixing the nodes that you set to 0?

Comment: @coldspeed Thank you for your reply. But I want to build my own neural network for my purpose.